# Org-Export does not respect (global-)auto-revert-mode

Tags: org-export, auto-revert-mode, global-auto-revert-mode

When exporting an *org* document to *pdf* via *LaTeX*, `C-c C-e l o`, if the pdf to be generated has already been visited in an existing buffer, neither of the variables `auto-revert-mode` nor `global-auto-revert-mode` are respected.

During the export process, `org-export-dispatch` calls `org-open-file` which in turn calls `find-file-other-window`, which in turn causes part of the problem by calling `find-file-noselect` with its *nowarn* argument set to *nil*.

I'm not sure of the best way to go about this, but I believe the solution would be to modify the `yes-or-no-p` statement, lines 2040 - 2055 of ...*/emacs/26.0.50/lisp/files.el.gz*:

...

```
        ((yes-or-no-p
          (if (string= (file-name-nondirectory filename)
                   (buffer-name buf))
              (format
               (if (buffer-modified-p buf)
               "File %s changed on disk.  Discard your edits? "
             "File %s changed on disk.  Reread from disk? ")
               (file-name-nondirectory filename))
            (format
             (if (buffer-modified-p buf)
             "File %s changed on disk.  Discard your edits in %s? "
               "File %s changed on disk.  Reread from disk into %s? ")
             (file-name-nondirectory filename)
             (buffer-name buf))))
         (with-current-buffer buf
           (revert-buffer t t)))))
```

...

such that when the buffer is **not** modified and `(global-)auto-revert-mode` is set, then automatically return `yes` without prompt.

Not sure if this should be filed as a bug?

When I compile the corresponding *tex* file that is generated as part of the `org-export` process, `(global-)auto-revert-mode` is respected, and the *pdf* buffer is automatically reverted.

**Edit**

This issue does **not** manifest itself when I start a *standalone* Emacs session, and *manually* open the compiled pdf with `C-x C-f`.

It does however, when I am working within a daemon, through `emacsclient -c -a ""`. Emacsclient is my *default application* for opening pdfs. I.e. in my init file, I have `(setq org-file-apps '(("\\.pdf\\'" . "emacsclient \"%s\"")))`

Comment: I think it might be more appropriate to modify `org-export-dispatch` or `org-open-file` to check if the file is already being visited in a buffer and respond accordingly. If you don't get a response here, this would be worth raising on the org-mode mailing list.